# The ultimate fake it 'till you make it

Tags: riddle

> Because of me, you are:
>
> here and there
>
> moving and still
>
> seeing and blind
>
> hearing and deaf
>
> together and apart
>
> knowing and unaware.
>
> I am found by those who pretend they have already found me.
>
> I am universal with infinite universes.
>
> Without me, you die.

What am I?

Hint

> omegaomegaomegaomegaomega

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the hint gave it away.

> Sleep

here and there:

> you are still alive in the real world while sleeping, but you are also in a dream

moving and still:

> you are still in real life but may be moving in a dream

seeing and blind:

> you may see things in a dream but you can't see anything in real life

hearing and deaf:

> you may imagine hearing things in a dream but you can't in real life

together and apart:

> not sure

knowing and unaware:

> you know things still, and it's a common belief that you can learn or work on things while you sleep, even though you are unaware of your surroundings

I am found by those who pretend they have already found me.

> if you pretend to be asleep for long enough, you may eventually actually fall asleep due to resting for an elongated period of time

I am universal with infinite universes.

> There are a potentially infinite number of dreams possible.

Without me, you die.

> Without sleep, you die.

Hint:

> omega is the last letter of the greek alphabet. the last letter of the english alphabet is z. zzzzzzz is a common onomatopoeic effect to show someone sleeping or snoring.

Comment: Fantastic answer!